# Web service error for Multi device hybrid apps

Tags: javascript, web-services, visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I got multi device hybrid apps web service problem.I want to use web service for phone apps. I am try to use ajax for web service but when  I start ripple emulator and click button 'send' it gives "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)" error. But if I change solution platform to Windows-x64 it works fine.

Here ;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Web Service Test</title>

<script src="js/JavaScriptjs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function SendMail() {                  

        var parameters = "{'userName':'" + 'blablabla' + "','userEmail':'" + 'blabla@blabla.com' + "','Subject':'" + 'blabla' + "','userMessage':'" + 'bla' + "'}";            

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.teknobilsoft.com/WsTeknobilsoft.asmx/SendMailMessage",
            data: parameters,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            processdata: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },

        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <form name="Demo" action="" method="post">
     <div>
         <input type="button" value="send" onclick="SendMail();" />
     </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Can you detect problem please?

Comment: What is the exception on the server that is throwing the 500?

Comment: And if you get it to work, I would obfuscate that url from this message, or you are gonna be a spam relay real soon..

Comment: File: xhr_proxy, Line: 0, Column: 0

Comment: and if i change xml to json it becomes "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

Comment: Are you sure this service even accepts json or xml? The key is to get the stacktrace of the server, without that it's just guess work

Comment: As I told before it works perfect with windows platform so i dont think its because of web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the ripple emulator has problems with http POSTs:

There is an open [Ripple issue](https://github.com/phonegap/emulate.phonegap.com/issues/6) about it.

Comment: Hmm i see, but funny part It dont work in emulator or real device either.

Comment: Hmm.. that's unexpected, which device are you using? And is the error the same?

Comment: Well seems odd but i fix issue with
               data:json.stringify(paramaters)